# How can I modify exif data of an image with PHP

Tags: php, exif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add exif data to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229446/how-do-i-add-exif-data-to-an-image)

I want to modify some information in exif data with PHP. I've googled around but no hope. There's function in PHP, exif_read_data. But it only reads not writes. Anybody knows how or walkaround?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229446/how-do-i-add-exif-data-to-an-image?

Comment: You can use exiftool or mogrify or PEL to edit the exif data of images. Also you have iptcembed function in PHP to edit the IPTC header info of images.

Answer (score 3):

Looks fairly old but may be something for you: http://pel.sourceforge.net/

This gets also mentioned in the linked article from Calvin L.

Answer (score 2):

http://pel.sourceforge.net/

A php extension that can write exif data, with installation instructions using PEAR. It requires that you can control which extensions are being installed on the machine that runs your PHP, which is not the case in many virtual hosting environments.