# How can I embed some EXIF data into JPEG?

Tags: php, exif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add exif data to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229446/how-do-i-add-exif-data-to-an-image)

How can I embed some EXIF data into JPEG (ie. description, copyright notice, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

you could use this tool for php http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1042-PHP-EXIF-information-reader-and-writer.html