# What function is for embeding exif data?

Tags: php, exif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add exif data to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229446/how-do-i-add-exif-data-to-an-image)

exif_read_data() is for reading exif data, but what function is for embeding exif data?

Comment: see all this answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229446/how-do-i-add-exif-data-to-an-image

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there's no built-in support for that (?). 
However I found something called [phpExifRW](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1042-PHP-EXIF-information-reader-and-writer.html) which seems to do the job. I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 0):

There's no native means of writing EXIF data (although you can natively write IPTC data via [iptcembed](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iptcembed.php) which might be sufficient).

However, you might want to take a look at the [pel library](https://github.com/lsolesen/pel/) - it's actively developed and has good examples, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Imagick](http://at.php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php). It's very fast and powerfull and has it's own PHP extension. It has a [setImageProperty](http://at.php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-setimageproperty.php) method.

Example from the docs:

```
$image = new Imagick();
$image->newImage(300, 200, "black");

$image->setImageProperty('Exif:Make', 'Imagick');
echo $image->getImageProperty('Exif:Make');
```

PEL seems fine though, just used to do it with Imagick.