# how to write exif details in to an image using php

Tags: php, exif

I have an resized image which doesnt have a exiff data . But the EXIF values are stored in DB when the original image is uploaded.

Now i want to write the EXIF value from DB to the resized image. Can anybody help me in resolving this ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add exif data to an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229446/how-do-i-add-exif-data-to-an-image)

Answer (score 0):

check out [PHP-EXIF-information-reader-and-writer](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/1042-PHP-EXIF-information-reader-and-writer.html) class