# Write EXIF into JPG with PHP

Tags: php, exif, imagick

For a couple of days I'm trying to write (or update) EXIF information (geotag, latitude and longitude) in a JPG image using PHP.
After consulting many sites without success I think the best option is to use Imagick but although it seems I can set the latitude and longitude with setImageProperty(), but when I write the picture the EXIF is not saved.

Here I give a code fragment:

```
//Loading existing image
$edited = new Imagick(dirname(__FILE__)."/mini.jpg");
//Stripping the curren EXIF info. I think is not mandatory and I try to comment but nothing...
$edited->stripImage();
//Setting the new properties
$edited->setImageProperty('exif:GPSLatitude', '30/1, 46/1, 58605/1000');
$edited->setImageProperty('exif:GPSLongitude', '63/1, 57/1, 35550/1000');
$propiedades = $edited->getImageProperties();
var_dump($propiedades);
var_dump($edited->writeImage('mini_edited.jpg'));


//reading the new image EXIF Info
$readedited = new Imagick(dirname(__FILE__)."/mini_edited.jpg");
$propiedades_edited = $readedited->getImageProperties();
```

The image is saved successfully but no the exif information updates.

Anyone have an idea how I can solve this problem with this or any other tool?
The only requirement is to use PHP

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add exif data to an image?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/229446/how-do-i-add-exif-data-to-an-image)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way I've found is to install [PEL - the PHP Exif Library](https://github.com/pel/pel)

Comment: Terecen Eden, I've been testing PEL appears to work well.
Thank you!

Answer (score -3):

The **gd** or **ImageMagick** libraries will help you do this sort of thing.
If you are using shared hosting one (or both of them) may have been installed for you.

Comment: Thanks but seems gb ad ImageMagick cant write EXIF tags