# Really hidden watermark image, audio and video PHP

Tags: php, image, audio, video, watermark

How do you insert a watermark/copyright/author inside the sourcecode of the file, without making the file corrupt? Not the layer on layer method.

I have seen this on multiple videos, audios and images before so it must be possible.

Disclaimer:
I already know how to put a watermark on videos and images with layer on layer method, but that is not what I am after this time.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "layer on layer method"? A watermark applied on a video or JPG/PNG bitmap isn't easily retouchable. Those formats don't support layers.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

Comment: @Pekka: It is retouchable even if it is not easy. View the source of an image, video or audio, that is where I have seen the watermark, I wan't to replicate that.

Comment: @Jari: Not what I am looking for, please read further before answering.

Comment: There is no way to build a watermark that is not retouchable at all, apart from killing every person on the planet who has the necessary skills, or destroying all photo retouching tools. Please clarify what you are trying to do. Make examples - what does a "layered" watermark look like and how is it different from what you want to do? Are we talking about a *visual* watermark at all here?

Comment: @Pekka: On my phone at the moment, will re-create the problem in a moment. Meanwhile, please view the source of an image. You'll see a lot of random text. In there you also might see clear text. But adding it yourself will make the file corrupt since it is not done properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Meanwhile, please view the source of an image. You'll see a lot of random text. In there you also might see clear text. But adding it yourself will make the file corrupt since it is not done properly.

That information called "Metadata". You can add Metadata to many video/audio formats. However, this data is *extremely* easy to remove, much easier than a visual watermark that requires retouching work. A simple re-encoding or "Open" / "Save as..." in your editor of choice will often destroy any metadata that there was.

A proper visual watermark is usually the much, much more reliable option.

If you want to continue on this path anyway, here are some related links:

For images:

- [writing exif data in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5384962/writing-exif-data-in-php)
- [Write EXIF into JPG with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001012/write-exif-into-jpg-with-php)

For video:

- [A simple PHP class to read and write FLV meta data and cue points in Flash Video (FLV) files.](https://code.google.com/p/php-flvinfo/)
- [Supplying FFmpeg With Metadata](http://multimedia.cx/eggs/supplying-ffmpeg-with-metadata/)

Comment: I have been testing that method before but is not exactly what i want to replicate. but it is close. The files that I viewed some time ago did not have this watermark information in Meta-Data but it was still written into the file. it is a step further in what I want, but not giving the results i am after.

Comment: @Ohtacaro what you're looking for isn't possible. Any information that you put into a file has to conform to the file format somehow. And even if you manage to cram some string into the file, *it'll be lost when it's saved or re-encoded.* As a means of copy protection, this is a completely pointless endeavour.

Comment: I will be looking further into this. Thanks!