# Edit exif data of an image

Tags: php, exif

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I add exif data to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229446/how-do-i-add-exif-data-to-an-image)

Do anyone know the php code or script for edit exif data of an image.?

Not "viewing exif data"   "edit exif data"