# Embedding name into picture

Tags: php, javascript, html, image

I currently have a section of my site where the user uploads a picture and provide their first and last name...

Is there a way that there name can be embedded into there picture and then saved?

Comment: We have databases for that.

Comment: Yes. There is. GD or imagick... Try http://php.net

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add text to a photo in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9900911/how-to-add-text-to-a-photo-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Watermark will fill your needs :)

```
   <?php
    function watermarkImage ($SourceFile, $WaterMarkText, $DestinationFile) { 
       list($width, $height) = getimagesize($SourceFile);
       $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
       $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($SourceFile);
       imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $width, $height); 
       $black = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0);
       $font = 'arial.ttf';
       $font_size = 10; 
       imagettftext($image_p, $font_size, 0, 10, 20, $black, $font, $WaterMarkText);
       if ($DestinationFile<>'') {
          imagejpeg ($image_p, $DestinationFile, 100); 
       } else {
          header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
          imagejpeg($image_p, null, 100);
       };
       imagedestroy($image); 
       imagedestroy($image_p); 
    };
    ?>
```

Source: http://www.phpjabbers.com/put-watermark-on-images-using-php-php20.html

Answer (score -1):

You have a lot of possibilities to do that. It depends on the infrastructure, the servers and the languages/technologies you are using or want to use...

1) You can store the meta-data in a database and add the link to the
   picture to it. (a often very used way)

2) you can store the meta-data in the database and the
   picture file as well

3) you can try to handle with exif data
   ([How do I add exif data to an image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/229446/how-do-i-add-exif-data-to-an-image))
   (I've never done that)

4) another way would be to store the meta-data
   in a xml file wich is stored at the same place than the picture...

Comment: How would I do option 4? The user is supplying their name and their picture

Comment: When the upload is done, you just have to write in a XML file (created by yourself just before).. Ithink you're working in PHP right?

Comment: yes... i want to implement it with http://tutorialzine.com/2011/04/jquery-webcam-photobooth/

Comment: I think in this case, one XML file in the folder is enough. So you'll have a list like : 
<photo>
   <user>Name...</user>
   <file>foo.jpg</file>
</photo>
(for each file...)

Comment: Ah.. and the only info you want to store is the name and the name of the person? If it's that, be simple, just rename the photo like "name_photo.jpg"

Comment: Okay... But then I also want to embed the person's name into there photo.. like another layer

Comment: "another layer"?... I'm not sure to understand..

Comment: like let's say my name is bob and i upload a picture of me.. Before the image is saved into the website file, I want it to say bob on the left hand corner of the picture

Comment: okay so like a copyright like a watermark?
---> http://php.net/manual/en/image.examples.merged-watermark.php

Comment: yes that something similiar.. how would i do that with a user inputted name?

Comment: simply with PHP: http://www.phpjabbers.com/put-watermark-on-images-using-php-php20.html