# Stitching thermal image with metadata integrity

Tags: python, image, opencv, flir

I am working on a project which use thermal imagery. I have found scripts to be able to extract temperature data from the pixel values within the image. I run `exiftool` on the image and get the following output, confirming that the image was taken with a FLIR camera and different calibration values.

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.80
File Name                       : DJI_0436.jpg
Directory                       : /home/saiperi/Documents/u-value_calc/Image
File Size                       : 714 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2019:07:15 13:03:24-05:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2019:07:19 13:01:07-05:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2019:07:15 14:54:58-05:00
File Permissions                : rw-r--r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Exif Byte Order                 : Little-endian (Intel, II)
Make                            : DJI
Camera Model Name               : FLIR
X Resolution                    : 1
Y Resolution                    : 1
Resolution Unit                 : None
Software                        : 01.15.00.59
Modify Date                     : 2019:04:25 11:54:08
F Number                        : 1.4
Aperture Value                  : 1.6
Focal Length                    : 9.0 mm
Sub Sec Time Original           : 161
Focal Plane Resolution Unit     : mm
GPS Latitude Ref                : North
GPS Longitude Ref               : West
GPS Altitude Ref                : Above Sea Level
GPS Map Datum                   : WGS-84
Compression                     : JPEG (old-style)
Thumbnail Offset                : 576
Thumbnail Length                : 5455
About                           : DJI Meta Data
Absolute Altitude               : 672.399048
Relative Altitude               : 5.800000
Gimbal Roll Degree              : 0.000000
Gimbal Yaw Degree               : 100.599998
Gimbal Pitch Degree             : 0.000000
Flight Roll Degree              : -1.000000
Flight Yaw Degree               : 101.099998
Flight Pitch Degree             : 4.500000
Central Temperature             : 27
Tlinear Gain                    : 0
Band Name                       : LWIR
Central Wavelength              : 10000
Wavelength FWHM                 : 4500
Creator Software                : ATAU_RBFO
Raw Thermal Image Width         : 640
Raw Thermal Image Height        : 512
Raw Thermal Image Type          : TIFF
Raw Thermal Image               : (Binary data 655564 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Emissivity                      : 1.00
Object Distance                 : 20.00 m
Reflected Apparent Temperature  : 22.0 C
Atmospheric Temperature         : 22.0 C
IR Window Temperature           : 22.0 C
IR Window Transmission          : 1.00
Relative Humidity               : 50.0 %
Planck R1                       : 17096.453
Planck B                        : 1428
Planck F                        : 1
Atmospheric Trans Alpha 1       : 0.006569
Atmospheric Trans Alpha 2       : 0.012620
Atmospheric Trans Beta 1        : -0.002276
Atmospheric Trans Beta 2        : -0.006670
Atmospheric Trans X             : 1.900000
Camera Temperature Range Max    : 135.0 C
Camera Temperature Range Min    : -25.0 C
Camera Temperature Max Clip     : 150.0 C
Camera Temperature Min Clip     : -60.0 C
Camera Temperature Max Warn     : 135.0 C
Camera Temperature Min Warn     : -25.0 C
Camera Temperature Max Saturated: 150.0 C
Camera Temperature Min Saturated: -60.0 C
Camera Model                    : 
Camera Part Number              : 
Camera Serial Number            : 
Camera Software                 : 
Lens Model                      : 
Lens Part Number                : 
Lens Serial Number              : 
Field Of View                   : 0.0 deg
Filter Model                    : 
Filter Part Number              : 
Filter Serial Number            : 
Planck O                        : -1123
Planck R2                       : 0.062614508
Raw Value Median                : 3010
Raw Value Range                 : 1811
Date/Time Original              : 2019:04:25 11:54:08.158+00:00
Focus Step Count                : 0
Focus Distance                  : 0.0 m
Frame Rate                      : 0
Image Width                     : 640
Image Height                    : 512
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Aperture                        : 1.4
Image Size                      : 640x512
Megapixels                      : 0.328
Peak Spectral Sensitivity       : 10.1 um
Date/Time Original              : 2019:04:25 11:54:08.161
Thumbnail Image                 : (Binary data 5455 bytes, use -b option to extract)
Focal Length                    : 9.0 mm
```

I am using OpenCV and the ORB algorithm in order to stitch the two images together. Afterwards my intension is to run it through scripts to extract the temperature data then. But it seems that after the stitching process the format and all the metadata associated with the image gets rewritten. The stitched images metadata is as follows:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.80
File Name                       : 4 images.jpg
Directory                       : /home/saiperi/Desktop
File Size                       : 127 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2019:07:15 16:32:12-05:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2019:07:19 14:40:53-05:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2019:07:19 14:41:00-05:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : JPEG
File Type Extension             : jpg
MIME Type                       : image/jpeg
JFIF Version                    : 1.01
Resolution Unit                 : None
X Resolution                    : 1
Y Resolution                    : 1
Image Width                     : 3840
Image Height                    : 512
Encoding Process                : Baseline DCT, Huffman coding
Bits Per Sample                 : 8
Color Components                : 3
Y Cb Cr Sub Sampling            : YCbCr4:2:0 (2 2)
Image Size                      : 3840x512
Megapixels                      : 2.0
```

My question is whether I can stitch the two or more images together (taken seconds within eachother) and keep the metadata from the first output. I am using a basic image stitching tutorial from google in python but substituted the SIFT algorithm for ORB.

Comment: I described a technique that you could use here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/34352134/2836621

Comment: Did my suggestion work for you?

Comment: @Mark Setchell I am going a different route. I am trying to extract temperatures from the images independently and try to apply the homography used to calculate how/where to stitch the csv. From my understanding (sx,sy,ssigma)= H(x,y,sigma) where S is the scale. Im hoping I can use this relationship to figure out the proper temperatures.